# LeetCode Java - Frequency of the most frequent element

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

So I was trying to solve the LeetCode question n.1838 ([Frequency of the most frequent element](https://leetcode.com/problems/frequency-of-the-most-frequent-element/)) and it works except for a test case with an input array of 500000 elements (1 <= nums.length <= 10^5): it gives me TimeLimitExceeded and I don't understand why.
I tried to explain my approach with comments in the code, but it's very easy: I sort the array first so I can start from the last element (the bigger one), I loop the array and for each element in the array i calculate the frequency for different cases:

- if nums[i] == nums[i - 1] increment the frequency
- if k < nums[i] - nums[i - 1] there's no need to do anything, so i just update j to get outside of the loop
- else I add to nums[i - 1] the difference so it can be nums[i], I update q and num.

I then update the max frequency and once I'm outside the while loop I do the same for each element of the array.

Here's my method:

```
public int maxFrequency(int[] nums, int k) {
    //corner case
    if (nums.length == 1)
        return 1;
    
    //order array
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    
    int max = 0; 
    int freq = 0;
    int num = 0; //will always be the int at the index - j (j will be incremented each time)
    int j = 0;
    
    //start from the last element of the array
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        num = nums[i - j];
        int q = k;
        while (q >= 0 && i - j >= 0) {
            //if element equals itself, increment frequency
            if (nums[i] - num == 0) {
                freq++;
                j++;
            } // if k < nums[i] - num (aka even if we add k to num we won't have a new nums[i])
            else if (nums[i] - num > q) {
                j = i + 1; //to get out of the while loop
            } else { //case where i can add k because k >= nums[i] - num
                q -= nums[i] - num;
                freq++;
                j++;
            } // update num only if i - j > 0 so we dont have ArrayOutOfBoundException
            if (i - j >= 0) {
                num = nums[i - j];
            } //update max frequency
            max = Math.max(freq, max);
        }
        freq = 0;
        j = 0;
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Any advice or hint would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already using `O(n log n)` when you sort the array. That's a lot of time going for just preparations.

Comment: Add Some traces in your loop in case of Some conditions gives Infinite loop ?

Comment: @Kayaman Do you think the whole ting can be done in less than O(n log n)? My feeling is it can’t. artificialdeathinthewest, I haven’t understood the code, but the two nested loops make me worry whether the whole program is O(n^2), which it certainly needs not be.

Comment: @OleV.V. well trading space for time in small cases like 500000 numbers, we can create a frequency map and find the highest one in O(n).

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for the answers and insights, I didn't know that an algorithm with O(n^2) temporal complexity would cause troubles with a huge input. Unfortunately isn't about just looking for a frequency, otherwise I would've simply used a hashmap to store the pair (int value, counter frequency) but given an int k you can increment numbers inside the array nums[] by 1 k times and return the maximum frequency you can achieve by incrementing the integers.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for the answers and insights, I didn't know that an algorithm with O(n^2) temporal complexity would cause troubles with a huge input. Unfortunately isn't about just looking for a frequency, otherwise I would've simply used a hashmap to store the pair (int value, counter frequency) but given an int k you can increment numbers inside the array nums[] by 1 k times and return the maximum frequency you can achieve by incrementing the integers.

Comment: I see. Now I also followed your link. I still think that @Kayaman’s frequency array/map is useful as long as you use a navigable map. To see how frequent you can make a number, say, 13, you also need to look at the frequencies of 12, 11, etc. until you have run out of increments you can make. Time complexity may come up in the n*k range. Whether that’s an improvement, i can’t tell.